# CodeIgniter - pass variables to CSS

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter

I'm rewriting website on Code Igniter, and i need to load external TTF. MySQL db points path to that TTFs. Can I pass somehow these variables to CSS and make foreach loop to 'loads' these fonts.

I tried

```
$this->load->vars($data);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to understand how you retrieve data from db and how you display them:
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/index.html
good luck

EDIT:
what you need is probably something like that:
after you have retrieved the links from database and let's say you called them $ttf_links

```
 <?php 
          foreach($ttf_links as $link){
        echo "<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href={$link['row_name']} media='screen' />"
    }
    ?>
```

and then call the fonts you need in your css

Comment: I retrieved data from db in controller. and I want to pass it to view->css.

Comment: That way works. But is it the correct way? By that way I re-include css because every single font ? What about overload ?

Comment: what I would do is including a string (or an array of links) in my config file and call it in view from there and not calling it again and again and again from database everytime I load the page

Comment: @Rabidmchine9 - problem i that my data is only in controller... not config.

Comment: what do you mean you data is only in controller?

Answer (score 6):

First, deal with serving dynamic CSS. My site has a controller called "resource" which allows me to serve CSS, JS, etc. (maybe images in the future).  It loads views based upon the segments passed to it in the url.

So, when `http://mysite.com/resource/css/main.css` is requested:

- My `Resource` controller (`.../controllers/resource`) handles any specifics of data handling (as is general with an MVC controller). It then loads:
- A generic view: `".../views/resources/css.php"`, passing it the name of the desired css file. This view prints out the header, specifying the Content-Type (important!) and any other generic stuff. Then it proceeds to load:
- The actual CSS file specified, here `".../views/resources/css/main.css.php"`.

It's a little overkill, but allows for a lot of flexibility, like you sound like you need.

**Controller:**

```
...
$segments = $this->uri->segment_array();
array_shift($segments);   // remove the first two
array_shift($segments);
$content['stylesheet'] = $segments[0] . ".php";  //e.g. main.css.php
$content['data'] = array();                      //Font data, etc
$this->load->view('resources/css.php', $content);
..
```

**Generic resources/css.php**
This loads up the actual .css.php stylesheet

```
<?php header("Content-Type: text/css"); // This is key! ?>  
/* MySite CSS File (c) 2011 bla bla */
<?php
     $this->load->view("resources/css/$stylesheet", $data);
     echo "\n";
?>
```

**Specific resources/css/main.css.php**

```
<?php echo "/* I can use PHP in my CSS! */\n"; ?>
body { background-color: <?=$data['bg_color']?>; }
p { font-family: <?=$data['p_font_fam'];?>; }
```

Comment: In that way do I need to put link in body of my pages... ? Or just that. Actually Im using view that loads 3 sub views. 
1st view: header,2nd : content, 3rd : footer.

Comment: Yes, you still need to include the CSS file in your HTML, just as if it were a regular, static css file:
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/resource/css/main.css" />

Answer (score 1):

Passing variables to a CSS doesn't work for as far as I know.

I have read something about CSS templating with PHP, but I can't find the link anymore. Will update this answer as soon as I found the link. But you could look for it yourself as well.

*Update*

Found it!: http://www.barelyfitz.com/projects/csscolor/

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I see you doing this is with file level CSS and changing values the usual way.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround would be to use CSS in the page itself to load the fonts.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer , I have implemented this and works fine

https://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/220105/#1014374